# HTML template gzip doesn't work (PageSpeed Insights)

Tags: html, .htaccess, gzip

I would like to ask how to make compression working on HTML template on 000webhost.com I created .htaccess file and added this:

```
    <ifModule mod_gzip.c> 
     mod_gzip_on Yes
     mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
     mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
     mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
     mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
     mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
     mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
     mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
     </ifModule>

     <IfModule mod_expires.c>
      ExpiresActive On
      ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
      ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
      ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
      ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
      ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
      ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
      ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
      ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
      ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
      ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
    </IfModule>
```

Google's PageSpeed Insights tells me that I didn't enable gzip compression, so I dont' know how to enable it properly.

Here is my [website](http://testerix.site90.com/)

And generally, I would like to know how can I improve performance of my website? Well, at the moment my website has **56/100** mobile and **73/100** according to PageSpeed Insights.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess would be a more normal way to do that.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    # Force compression for mangled headers.
    # http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
    # (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`
    #  and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines
    #  as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives).
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                      application/javascript \
                                      application/json \
                                      application/ld+json \
                                      application/rss+xml \
                                      application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                      application/x-font-ttf \
                                      application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                                      application/xhtml+xml \
                                      application/xml \
                                      font/opentype \
                                      image/svg+xml \
                                      image/x-icon \
                                      text/css \
                                      text/html \
                                      text/plain \
                                      text/x-component \
                                      text/xml
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

That whole file is worth reading through, lots of good stuff in there.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works or maybe I'm doing something wrong but it doesn't change anything. I still get message about compression and well the same rating on mobile and desktop. Maybe it doesn't work because I use free hosting or my HTML document is bugged?

Comment: The ifmodule bits ensure the code only runs if the correct Apache modules are installed and active. You may need to turn them on using a2enmod. If its free hosting, you are probably our of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I used defalte mod instead of gzip:

Here is the code:

```
# BEGIN DEFLATE COMPRESSION
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
</IfModule>
# END DEFLATE COMPRESSION
```

and for expire headers:

```
# Add Expire headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
<Filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|ico|woff|mp3)$">
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
</Filesmatch>
</IfModule>
```

References:

1. https://dzone.com/articles/steps-improve-your-pagespeed-insight-score
2. http://www.quickregisterseo.com/improve-google-page-speed-score-wordpress-without-plugins/

Current score of my website:
Desktop: 91
Mobile: 83